# Secret manager access denied issue with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I have a usecase to use the secret from A in all other accounts in that organization. I have provided permission for secret for organization and encrypted the secret with kms key . I have a role accross the organization which allows this secret to be accessed .

While fetching the secret from B using AWS CLI it works fine . But while fetching the secret using python boto3 , I am getting access denied .

Error :

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role// is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action

AWS cli list secrets as below :

```bash
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:291854329851:secret:D011358-f9gGzq --region eu-central-1
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:<acc number>:secret:Cuser-f9gGzq",
    "Name": "Cuser",
    "VersionId": "c4537bdf-3aff-4e13-b355-36890834a407",
    "SecretString": "{\"C user\":\"password"}",
    "VersionStages": [
        "AWSCURRENT"
    ],
    "CreatedDate": 1690539987.039
}
```

Secret permissin is as below :

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "AllowUseOfTheKey",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "*"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*",
    "Condition" : {
      "StringEquals" : {
        "aws:PrincipalOrgID" : "orgid"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Show us your Python script

Comment: python script :


import boto3


session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
service_name = 'secretsmanager',
region_name = 'eu-central-1'
)

get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId="Cuser"
  )

sec =json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])

Comment: Where is the Python script running? On your machine?

Comment: it gets executed in ec2 instances  during boot as cloud init scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it gets executed in ec2 instances during boot as cloud init scripts

You need to attach an IAM instance profile to the EC2 instance, and the instance profile needs to have an IAM role that has a policy which allows the policy you've defined.

For more reading:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html

Comment: instance is created in console and has instance profile and role which allows getsecret in policy

Comment: @Linuxuser well, clearly not properly. Show us screenshots of your configuration

Comment: @Linuxuser can you show us the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the secret is in Account A and you're trying to access it i.e. calling `GetSecretValue` from a different account in your Organizations. In this case, since the resource (i.e. the secret) is in a different account, it's resource-based policy is not enough and you must grant `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` permission through your IAM role's permission policy.

Comment: IAM role is available in all accounts in organization which has below policy:


       {
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:<acno>:key/<keynum>",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:<accno>:secret:<Cuser>-f9gGzq"
            ],
            "Sid": "SecretAccess"

By running locally fromany instnace in any account using awscli  it works